# How to summarize a dictionary per year with only reduce and map?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, reduce, summarize

I imported a .csv file using `csv.DictReader` and converted the dictionaries into a list:

```
dataset = list(file.csv)
```

In this list of dictionaries I need to count the number of type 1 and type 2 actions (sum of them) for each year. I would like to avoid using repeat loops and just use `reduce` and/or `map`

```
my_dict1 = {"Date": 2021-01-01, "Action1": 2, "Action2": 3}
my_dict1 = {"Date": 2021-02-01, "Action1": 3, "Action2": 3}
my_dict1 = {"Date": 2020-02-01, "Action1": 10, "Action2":9}
my_dict1 = {"Date": 2020-03-01, "Action1": 0, "Action2": 5}
```

I need the following output:

```
(2021, 11)
(2020, 24)
```

Comment: This is a challenge and this restriction has been imposed.

Comment: What I could imagine was separating the data according to the year (using conditional or filter) and then adding the number of actions for each year, but this doesn't seem to be the best option.
I am migrating from R to Python at the moment and still encounter some difficulties.

Comment: The challenge is to do this task using pure language and also with Pandas. With Pandas everything is easier and I managed to do it. But I'm having difficulties for this other part.

Comment: Why isn't it the best option? What exactly is the problem here? You can actually do this with a single reduce, although it will be ugly and unpythonic

Comment: Wait wait wait. If you just have to use vanilla Python, then just use a loop with a dict, which will be the most efficient and Pythonic way of doing it

Comment: The use of loops is not allowed.
It is requested to use reduce or map only.

I don't think it's the best option to separate the dataset into several other datasets per year because it's a long solution.
I imagine the reduce idea is similar to apply in R and that's what I'd like to do (although I'm at a loss as to how to do it).

Comment: No, reduce is not like apply in R. Apply is like map

Comment: Okay. I don't want a straight answer on how to solve the problem, but can you help me find the way?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Create list `llst` of year-action total pairs from the list of dictionaries,

(2) Using `functools.reduce`, create a dictionary in which the key-value pairs denote year-actions pairs, by adding the second items of tuples in `llst` if the first items match.

```
from functools import reduce
def add(d, x):
    d[x[0]] = d.get(x[0], 0) + x[1]
    return d

llst = map(lambda x: (int(x['Date'].split('-')[0]), x.get('Action1', 0) + x.get('Action2', 0)), lst)
out = list(reduce(add, llst, {}).items())
```

Output:

```
[(2021, 11), (2020, 24)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question, you have a list of dicts, each of them composed in the following manner:

```
{"Date": "2021-01-01", "Action1": 2, "Action2": 3}
```

Date being a string and Action1 and Action2 being integers.

You need to get the sum of all actions for each separate year using only map and reduce and no loops (actually reduce and map implement loops in the background, but ok).

First thing to do is define a function to sum the actions in a dict and marks them with the correct year:

```
def sum_actions(dict_input: dict) -> dict:
    date_of_actions = dict_input["Date"][0:4]
    sum_of_actions = dict_input["Action1"] + dict_input["Action2"]
    return {"Date": date_of_actions, "Sum": sum_of_actions}
```

now you can just map this function to the list of dicts:

```
mapped_list = map(sum_actions, dataset)
```

From this you obtain a list of dicts (actually a map object that can be converted to a list) containing the year of entry and the sum of its actions:

```
[
{"Date" : "2021", "Sum": 12},
{"Date" : "2020", "Sum": 8},
...,
{"Date" : "2021", "Sum": 15},
]
```

Now you can store the sum of each year inside an object (I'll be using a dict).

You can just develop a function that will add the each entry to the sum inside a dict and pass it to reduce with an empty dict as initializer:

```
from functools import reduce

def sum_actions_in_year(value, element):
    element_year = element["Date"]
    element_sum = element["Sum"]
    
    if value.get(element_year): 
        value[element_year] = value[element_year] + element_sum
    else:
        value[element_year] = element_sum
    return value

result = reduce(sum_actions_in_year, mapped_list, {})
```

This will return a dict with the following key-value pairs:

```
{YEAR: SUM_OF_YEAR,
YEAR: SUM_OF_YEAR}
```

If the answer needs to be in tupples you can just convert it:

```
list_of_tuples = list(result.items())
```